# Image gallery + zoom compatible with IE6

Tags: jquery, zooming, image-gallery

I am working on a new project which requires a image gallery as well as a zoom feature in it and compatible with IE6.

I've searched for a plugin that has both the features everywhere. Hence I've come here to find some help.

For zoom, I tried jqzoom and professorcloud which are excellent but without the gallery option.

For Gallery, I tried with galleria. But just now figured it out that it doesnt support IE6.

Will be grateful for any kind of advice or guide me in the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Galleria FAQ](http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/references/faq/) state:

> IE6 is not supported by any theme at this point, but Galleria itself supports it so you can patch a theme yourself if you need IE6 compliance (we don’t really see the point though).

so it might be worth looking into it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.browser` shows u which browser the user is using and which version under it.

that in mind, ie6 supports a zoom property in css, which does exactly that which you need so, `if` its ie6 do the css zoom `else` do the rest :)